# How find bag files in Ubuntu

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I recorded a .bag file and then played it and it worked.Now I cannot find where it is saved in my filesystem.Any suggestion?
Also maybe I messed around with something because now it is showing this error:

sam@sam-ThinkStation-P300:~/catkin_ws$ rosbag info sadrecord.bag
ERROR reading sadrecord.bag: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sadrecord.bag'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211393/how-find-bag-files-in-ubuntu/) by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo updatedb
locate sadrecord.bag
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on 2015-06-15**:
Thanks.Found it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bag files are saved at the directory where you run rosbag record.The problem is solved:)

---

Originally posted by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) with karma: 13 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was saved in your current directory, don't you remember what was your current directory, when you saved the bag file?
In a package where you were working or something..

---

Originally posted by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) with karma: 45 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1